# Stash forgetting value

Tags: add-on, stash, plugin

I have a plugin which is setting the value of a stash variable based on segment URIs.

on my redir/index.html template, I have `{exp:hippo_functions:redir}` and the contents of my function (stripped) is:

```
$params = array(
    'name' => 'delivery_day',
    'scope' => 'user'
);

Stash::set($params,$days['delivery_date']);

ee()->functions->redirect( ee()->functions->create_url($location) );
```

I've checked the value of the the 'delivery_day' stash immediately after setting it with `Stash::get('delivery_day');` and it's returning the correct value, however on my redirected page - I have a separate function which checks the validity of the date using the same `Stash::get('delivery_day');` call, however this time the value is empty.

Why isn't the value persisting across pages? I presumed it was the scope, which was why I set it to user - but could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Croxton for the answer... I needed to add `save => 'y'` to the params array.